# Analyzing runtime of function

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, big-o

[image: Click here to check question image]

Hello, I got this question, but got wrong on its answer that was about analyzing runtime of function.

From my perspective, outer while loop runs for n^2 times. Specifically it starts from 1 to n^2, thus, runtime is "n^2 - 1", then we call it just O(n^2) for simplicity.

And inner for loop runs for logn (base 2) times because division by 2.

Since it is nested loop, we have to multiply those 2 runtimes.

So whole runtime become O(n^2 * logn), however, my answer is wrong according to answer.

Can you explain the reason why answer is not O(n^2 * logn) but O(n^2)?

Comment: Assuming `n^2 >= 1`, the inner loop never executes at all, right?

Comment: @smarx good catch, didn't see that `j<1`, lol

Comment: Ah, just realized we don't have to assume anything... if the outer loop ever executes, the inner loop won't (because at the first iteration, `i == 1`, so we know `n^2 > 1`, and `i` only increases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop is never executed because `n²<1` is false, hence the `while` loop is executed `(n²-1)/2` times.

Comment: Sorry. does that mean that exact runtime could be "(n^2-1)/3" time if "i+=2" was "i += 3" instead, inside the while loop? or could be just "(n^2-1)/i" according to which value we increase with i?

Comment: there is no such variable k in this function